# How to create custom list with checkboxes and text

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

```
**Adapter class**
 public class checklist extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final ArrayList<String> name;

public checklist(Activity context,ArrayList<String> name) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_custm_list, name);
    this.context = context;
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custm_list, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.check);
    txtTitle.setText(name.get(position));

    return rowView;
}
```

}
**adapter_xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**listview_actitvty**

```
public class Delete extends ActionBarActivity {


ListView lv ;
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_delete);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    name = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("note name");
    ids = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("id");
    System.out.println("-------*********----------------"+name);
   // checklist dapter = new checklist(Delete.this,name);
    checklist adapter = new checklist(Delete.this, name);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

**activity_xml**

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mohamedreda.note.Delete">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**this output of system.out.print**
05-11 05:19:03.072    5464-5464/com.example.mohamedreda.note I/System.out﹕ -------*********----------------[alissaas, mes, hhhhhhhhh, meshoo, zeko, mostafaaaa, ahmed, hi, ahmedddd, kattttb, xxxxxxxxxxx, sssssssssssssss, -----------------------------------, a44444, n, no, mes2, zeko5, ahmed7]

**error**
*
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setTag(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.mohamedreda.note.checklist.getView(checklist.java:32)*

Comment: i need to display the checkbox and it not check

Comment: Exception you are getting and code you have posted do not match. There is no 'setTag' call in your posted 'checklist.getView' method.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.mohamedreda.note.checklist.getView(checklist.java:31)

Comment: i add         checkBox.setChecked(true);

Comment: your `name` list is `null`

Comment: but when i print name list before i pass it to adapter its have my data

Comment: what i do ? when i delete this code  checkBox.setChecked(true); i can see my customlist with my data but the checkboxes is not seen only saw my data in textview no checkboxes with it

Comment: :( any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

you can : `""+name.get(position);`

became :    `txtTitle.setText(""+name.get(position));`

Comment: thanks for your but i try it but no slove the problem my checkboxes is hidden i can't saw them in list in addition i saw my data that i pass in listview

Comment: i check but checkbox is show. error when 
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    name = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("note name");
you change:
  for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
            String po = "+"+i;
            name.add(po);
        }
        System.out.println("-------*********----------------"+name);

Comment: :( iam sorry thanks for your hard work but all my problem not in data that display i can see them its pass well but i can saw the check button in design :( help me please if u can